# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre int** x y int** funcion(int x)?

Tags: c++, punteros

Se que `int**` es un puntero a puntero. ¿Qué es entonces `int**funcion(int cosa);`?

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que una funcion `int** funcion(int m)` me de los valores desde `0` hasta `m`?

```
int** funcion(int m){
    return ???;
}

main{
    int m;
    funcion(m);
}
```

Comment: Tu español aún debe mejorar. No te ha respondido nadie porque no se te entiende bien ;-)

Comment: @Trauma Claro que si... Pero... estan mi unicos amigos de pluma para mejoralo :/  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int **funcion( int max )` es lo que parece, una función que devuelve un puntero a un puntero. El esquema es el mismo: `TipoDevuelto` `nombre` **(** `argumentos` **)**.

Con un poco de imaginación, el código que buscas es el siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>

int **doblesPunteros( int max ) {
  int **result = new int*[max];

  while( max-- ) {
    result[max] = new int;
    *result[max] = max;
  }

  return result;
}

int main( void ) {
  int count = 10;
  int **m = doblesPunteros( count );

  while( count-- )
    std::cout << *m[count] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

`doblesPunteros( )` es una función que devuelve un puntero a un *arreglo* de punteros, todo ello creado dinamicamente.